# Warning: Illegal string offset

Tags: php, arrays, string, oop, warnings

I new to oop and I have a image displaying when I had a single a array query (requesting the image url only) but when I added a second dimension to the query array (image id in the table) I just ended up getting a warning message  'Warning: Illegal string offset'. I have used mysqli_fetch_assoc in the database class and then running the result through a foreach loop.

This is the message I am getting.

Thanks in advance for any help given.

page code

```
$user = $_SESSION['user_name'];

        $query = "SELECT gallery_image, 'gallery_id' FROM gallery WHERE user_name = '$user' ORDER BY gallery_id DESC";
        $result = $obj_db->get_gallery($query);
        foreach ($result as $image ) {
            foreach ($image as $key => $value) {
                echo '<div class="gallery_item"><a href="proof.php?image='.$value['gallery_id'].'"><img src="'.$value['gallery_image'].'"></a></div>';
            }
        }
```

Database class code

```
function get_gallery($sql){
        $obj_res = mysqli_query($this->obj_db_conn, $sql);
            if(mysqli_errno($this->obj_db_conn)){
                    die ("Failed query: $strSql".$this->obj_db_conn->error);
     }
        $arResults = array();
                while($arRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($obj_res)){
                    $arResults[] = $arRow;

                }
                    return $arResults;
```

Comment: Remove the quotes => `'gallery_id'` that's a column, not a value. You're obviously not checking for errors; **do**.

Comment: Thanks, I have just tried that but sadly no luck.

Comment: It's part of the problem. Now, you need to check for errors elsewhere.

Comment: @SIH What line the warning is showing for?

Comment: The question I always dread asking: `session_start();` is loaded, *right?*

Comment: The undefined variable `$strSql` in the database class code.

Comment: @Sithu this error is coming from the the echoed line in page code(echo <div class=gallery....). It was working when I didn't call for the gallery_id.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes the session is working.

Comment: Have you removed the single quotes around `gallery_id`?

Comment: @Sithu Yes. I have run a var_dump on $result and this what I got.     Array ( [user_name] => admin [loggedin] => yes ) array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["gallery_image"]=> string(26) "./images/untitled-11-4.jpg" ["gallery_id"]=> string(2) "11" } [1]=> array(2) { ["gallery_image"]=> string(26) "./images/untitled-71-4.jpg" ["gallery_id"]=> string(2) "10" } }

Comment: @SIH `username` and `loggedin` could not come from the result of your query. Please check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26622333/1179841)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `var_dump` output on `$result` give this,

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> array(2) { 
        ["gallery_image"]=> ""
        ["gallery_id"]=> ""
    } 
    [1]=> array(2) { 
        ["gallery_image"]=> ""
        ["gallery_id"]=> ""
    } 
}
```

you don't need two nested `foreach` loops in your page code. The one `foreach` loop could be enough.

```
   $query = "SELECT gallery_image, gallery_id FROM gallery WHERE user_name = '$user' ORDER BY gallery_id DESC";
   $result = $obj_db->get_gallery($query);
   foreach ($result as $image ) {
        echo '<div class="gallery_item"><a href="proof.php?image='.$image['gallery_id'].'"><img src="'.$image['gallery_image'].'"></a></div>';
   }
```

Comment: Thank you @Sithu and Fred-ii-. Sithu that worked perfectly.